# indexing won't work when we have large amount of rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

When I am using small date range then indexing is working. query is

```
EXPLAIN select sum(principalBalance) as pos, count(id) as TotalCases, sum(amountPaid) as paid, count(amountPaid) as paidCount, sum(amountPdc) as Pdc,sum(amountPtp),count(amountPtp) from caseDetails USE index (updatedAt_caseDetails) where updatedAt between '2016/06/01 00:00:00' AND '2016/07/26 23:59:00'
```

Result of this query:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  caseDetails     range   updatedAt_caseDetails   updatedAt_caseDetails   6       607554  100 Using index condition; Using MRR
```

In this result you can see `key=updatedAt_caseDetails` indexing is working

But when we increase date range indexing wont work:

```
EXPLAIN select sum(principalBalance) as pos, count(id) as TotalCases, sum(amountPaid) as paid, count(amountPaid) as paidCount, sum(amountPdc) as Pdc,sum(amountPtp),count(amountPtp) from caseDetails USE index (updatedAt_caseDetails) where updatedAt between '2016/06/01 00:00:00' AND '2016/07/30 23:59:00'
```

Result of this query:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  caseDetails     ALL updatedAt_caseDetails               2898377 22.94   Using where
```

Answer (score 0):

I should use force index () instead of use index():
 using force index its working fine.

result query will be:

EXPLAIN select sum(principalBalance) as pos, count(id) as TotalCases, sum(amountPaid) as paid, count(amountPaid) as paidCount, sum(amountPdc) as Pdc,sum(amountPtp),count(amountPtp) 
from caseDetails **force index (updatedAt_caseDetails)** where updatedAt between '2016/06/01 00:00:00' AND '2016/07/26 23:59:00'

result will be:
[image]